# How to get the value from the next cell in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe contains an ID column, and the second a name column. An ID can have more than one name, but a name always belongs to a single ID.
I have a second dataframe, which have the name column as well.
What I would like to have is a new column in the second dataframe, with the matching IDs to the names. How do I do that?
I understand I create an empty column, than take the name as an input, search for that in the first dataframe's name column, and if I have a match, grab the ID from the next cell, and return that, but I cannot figure out how to that.

Comment: Can you add example data for better understanding of your question?

Comment: can you edit your question, show some dummy dataframe, required/desired output for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you have one table with ID and Name, and the second only with name and other data, let's say like the following:

Table 1 with `id` and `name`:

- an ID can have more than 1 name
- a name always belongs to a single ID

like this `df_name_id`:

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | name      |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | Arthur    |
| 1   | Brigit    |
| 2   | Christoph |
+-----+-----------+
```

Table 2 with other data and name (`df_data`):

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Other_data  | name      |
+-------------+-----------+
| 203423      | Arthur    |
| 125323      | Brigit    |
| 125323      | Christoph |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Then you can join the two dataframes on `name` to get the `id` to the second dataframe with your data:

```
df_combined = pd.merge(df_data, df_name_id, on='name', how='left')
```

Result looks like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+
| Other_data  | name      |  id   |
+-------------+-----------+-------+
| 203423      | Arthur    |  1    |
| 125323      | Brigit    |  1    |
| 125323      | Christoph |  2    |
+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: How can I solve the same problem if the "name" columns name are not the same? For example I have dataframe A: 1st_name, 2nd_name, and dataframe B: names, IDs, and I would need two other columns in df A:
1st_name, 1st_ID, 2nd_name, 2_ID
datastorage is very weird with this project I know.

Comment: you can just rename the `name` column in either dataframe with this: `df.rename(columns={'oldname':'newname', 'oldname2':'newname2'}, inplace=True)` so you have a common name in both dataframes.

Comment: thank you, I will try it without inplace, so I don't have to re-rename again.

Comment: if you do it without the `inplace` flag , `df.rename` will return a different dataframe - have look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `merge` function in Pandas. For more explanations see [this external page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). If you want to merge on more than one column you can pass a list of columns, e.g., `on=['key1', 'key2']`.

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name')
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want to `INNER JOIN` on `SECOND_NAME` (SQL logic). `pandas` comes with a neat functionality which allows you to merge dataframes on a specific column:
[see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
so you should be able to use this functionality to automatically join your dataframes. Try it yourself first and if you still struggle I'll send some examples